# Menu disappears after changing template

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.5

It's been awhile since I've used Joomla and I'm trying to get back into it. I just uploaded a new template that supports Joomla 3.5 and the minute I change to the template, the menu at the top goes away and the one that the demo shows for the template doesn't appear.

Is there anything that I need to change in Joomla after changing the template as well? I apologize for this question that may be answered somewhere already, but I'm really just having a hard time trying to find this information.

Comment: BTW THis was 3500th Question on JSE! Cheers mates! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Just figured this one out on my own. Had to go to the module and reassign positions to the new template.

Comment: Please be sure to mark your answer as accepted.